# Eval not showing correct date format in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, eval

This is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
EXPIRYTIME=30
dateformat=(date -d \"+ $EXPIRYTIME minutes\" +"%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S+00:00")
#dateformat=(date + "%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S+00:00")
expiry=$(eval $dateformat)
```

And it is showing wrong results, that is
Fri Aug 14 14:36:17 IST 2020\

But when I run in my cli it is showing right format that is:
2020-08-14T15-03-52+00:00

Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is with this line:

```
dateformat=(date -d \"+ $EXPIRYTIME minutes\" +"%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S+00:00")
```

where the `=(...)` says to assign an array of values to the `dateformat` variable.

Then `eval $dateformat` fails to provide an array subscript so bash will use whatever value is assigned to index=0 which in this case is `date`; net result is that you end up running `date` (with no args) and you get the current date/time.

You have a couple options:

1 - continue to use the array but make sure you reference the entire set of array indices:

```
$ dateformat=(date -d \"+ $EXPIRYTIME minutes\" +"%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S+00:00")
$ eval "${dateformat[@]}"
2020-08-14T04-53-55+00:00
```

2 - define the variable as a single string:

```
$ dateformat='date -d "+ '"${EXPIRYTIME}"' minutes" +"%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S+00:00"'
$ eval "${dateformat}"
2020-08-14T04-53-57+00:00
```

Keep in mind for this particular case there's no need for the `eval` as `${EXPIRYTIME}` can be fed directly to the `date` command:

```
$ date -d "+ ${EXPIRYTIME} minutes" +"%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S+00:00"
2020-08-14T04-53-58+00:00
```

**NOTE**: The above examples were run when local system time was Fri Aug 14 04:23:55 CDT 2020

Comment: Thank you very much for such a good explanation. It not only solve the problem but also clear the fundamentals.